# Test for Checkbox Checked in if Statement with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a page that contains a dropdown select list and a checkbox. If the user selects an item from the dropdown and the checkbox is checked I want several text entries filled in from a json call. I have the Json piece working from another page. My problem though is testing the state of the checkbox. Code is shown below. What is happening is either the code doesn’t run at all or, as with the code below, always equates to true. Not sure what I’m missing at this point and have tried several iterations.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#InstitutionID").change(SetAddress);

    function SetAddress() {
        if ($(“#AddressSameAsInstitute").val()) {
            var value = $("#InstitutionID").val();
            $.getJSON("GetInsitutionAddress", { institutionID: value }, function (data) {
                $("#Address1").val(data.Address1);
                $("#Address2").val(data.Address2);
                $("#City").val(data.City);
                $("#State").val(data.State);
                $("#Zip").val(data.Zip);
            });
        };
    };

</script>
```

I’m using ASP.net MVC and so the checkbox input is formed with the next line of code.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressSameAsInstitute, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The code “works” except that it works overtime even when the checkbox is not checked. Thanks.

Comment: try `checked`. like `if ($("#AddressSameAsInstitute").is(':checked'))`.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a million, Suchit. Is there a reason why the .checked interrogation doesn’t work? I’ve used $(this.checked) previously in a slightly different method.

Comment: Why the down vote? Please tell me what I did wrong so I can correct in the future or remove the down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for the `checked` property instead:

```
if ($("#AddressSameAsInstitute").prop('checked')) {
```